# How do I implement the string version of .split without using any methods or functions?

Tags: python, string, split

This is what I am asked with

Write a file named str_redux.py that implements versions of the string methods find and split without using any string methods or functions.

In particular, define a function myfind such that myfind(s,t) does the same thing that s.find(t) does; and a function mysplit such that mysplit(s,t) does the same thing that s.split(t) does.

You may not use any string methods in your solution. All operators (including in, [index], [i1:i2], etc) are fair game. None of the functions (nor the file itself) should print anything nor ask for any input.

In addition to functional correctness, some points will be reserved for

having good variable names
having meaningful docstrings for all functions you write

```
def myfind(whole,part):
"""Docstring: searches for a string (whole) for a segment which is (part) and returns the index"""

    if part in whole:
        for n in range(len(whole)):
            sub = whole[n:n+len(part)]

            if part in sub: #Use of if-in function to find out if our segment is in our word
                return n
                break
    else:
        return -1 # Doesn't exist within the string


def mysplit(whole, part):
    """Docstring: when given a word, will seperate the word into predetermined chunks"""

    split_word = []
    position_start = 0
    while part in whole [position_start::]:
        new_position = myfind(whole,part)
        split_segment = whole[position_start: new_position+position_start]
        split_word.append(split_segment)
        if new_position == -1:
            break
        position_start = new_position+len(part)+position_start
    split_word.append(whole[position_start:])
    return split_word
```

**When I test this:**

```
import str_redux

print(str_redux.myfind('divided','d'))
print(str_redux.myfind('divided','id'))
print(str_redux.myfind('divided','ido'))

print()

print(str_redux.mysplit('divided','d'))
print(str_redux.mysplit('divided','id'))
print(str_redux.mysplit('divided','ido'))
```

**I get:**

```
0
3
-1

['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
['div', 'ed']
['divided']
```

**When it should be:**

```
0
3
-1

['', 'ivi', 'e', '']
['div', 'ed']
['divided']
```

**Does anyone have a clue what I am doing wrong? I know my error is in the 2nd part of the code, but I am not sure where.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `new_position = myfind(whole,part)` will always return 0 because your testing the same thing each time.

`new_position = myfind(whole[position_start:], part)` I believe is what you had in mind.

Answer (score -1):

This is an alternative solution to your problem.

```
def splitter(mystr, char=','):
    var = ''
    n = len(mystr)
    for idx, i in enumerate(mystr, 1):
        if i != char:
            var += i
        if (i == char) or (idx == n):
            yield var
            var = ''

res = list(splitter('Hello, this is a test, see if it works!'))

# ['Hello', ' this is a test', ' see if it works!']
```